# React Select component not opening the drop down menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

i have a simple Select component in a React environment.
I simply need to use it as multi select menu of items, i tried to realize it and the drop down menu simply won't open, I checked plenty of forums to fix this thing but no solution seemed to work, so I'm really hoping for a turn around here.
Here is what my code looks like:

```
const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);
const [isMenuVisible, setIsMenuVisible] = useState(false);

const handleCloseMenu = () => setIsMenuVisible(false);
const handleOpenMenu = () => setIsMenuVisible(true);

// more code

const options = [
    {value: 'project1', label: 'project1'},
    {value: 'project2', label: 'project2'},
]

return(
    <div>
         <Select
             isMulti
             onMenuClose={handleCloseMenu}
             onMenuOpen={handleOpenMenu}
             menuIsOpen={isMenuVisible}
             options={options}
             onChange={setSelectedOptions}
         />
    </div>
);
```

I already checked that there aren't any overflow-hidden in some css cause i found out it can cause troubles, and also tried to remove the isMulti cause i thought maybe it was generating problems aswell, i really can't get it to work

I even tried to do something as basic as this and still doesn't work:

```
const options = [
            {value: 'ciao', label: 'ciao'}
        ];


        return(
            <div>
                <Select
                    options={options}
                />
            </div>
        );
```

Comment: I have tried to replicate your issue, but couldn't, It's working fine. If you wanna play around with [code](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/hopeful-khayyam-dqy6fk?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A12%2C47). Please make a seperate MultiSelectComponent :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, recently, when using the control inside a sized container. I got around the issue by using the `menuPortalTarget` prop.